# Does BIM 360 have an oAuth login for Field API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

The BIM 360 Field API documentation seems to indicate that it uses an entirely separate login, which requires the user to provide their username and password. I have two concerns with this:

1) My customer should not have to log in more than once, just so I can access different BIM 360 APIs.

2) It's not secure for the customer to provide me (the vendor) or anyone other than Autodesk with their username and password, so I suspect the separate BIM 360 Field login will be deprecated at some point.

Is there a way I can use the oAuth login used by other BIM 360 APIs to access Field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legacy BIM 360 Field is not based on Forge. It is using older technology. Unfortunately, you cannot use Forge oAuth.

(Field Management module, a.k.a. Next Gen Field, built on top of BIM 360 Docs is Forge. So in future the same feature or beyond will be accessible through the same credentials.)

Comment: Thanks Mikako, that's more or less what I expected. Do you know where I can find more about an API for the Field Management module?

Comment: API for Field Management is still to come. The product itself is still in preview. Hopefully we'll have API near future.